# How to prevent Firefox from downloading images twice

Tags: firefox

If Firefox loads an image completely in the viewport it shouldn't download it again if a user saves that image to a local storage medium.

Maybe because some websites disable user agent cache storage some images have to be downloaded again.

Is there a workaround for this?
PD: Firefox version is 26

Comment: Do you have an example of a website where this occurs? Also, which OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, www.panoramio.com.  Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bits service pack 1. Is the OS important in this case?

Comment: Try dragging the image to the desktop or any other folder, like if you were moving a file. It seems to use the cached version rather than redownload it. Of course this may not work in cases where the site is using Javascript to handle mouse events or uses tricks to stop people copying images.

Comment: The images I tried from that site seem to be cached. Try using NirSoft's Cache Viewer utility (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html) to see if the image you want is cached or not.